# A single BroadcastReceiver in an Android APK file.

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, receiver

Suppose we have an Android APK file which contains only a single BroadcastReceiver.
Will this form of the APK file be installed on Android devices be installed successfully and can the BR receive intended intents? I thought it will, but my experiment showed it does not. I am not sure why, but the installation of such APK files (with a single BR) seems to fail all the time.

A solution to this problem is to add a dummy Activity to the package. Then the installation succeeds, and the BroadcastReceiver can receive all intended intents!

Please share your opinion on this matter.

I always thanks you all for helps!

Comment: Post your code and the error you are seeing. Widgets are receivers and can work fine with no activity at all in your application but I can't tell if you are doing that or not.

Comment: Adding a dummy activity, solved the issue. Did you set up this dummy activity in your manifest as launcher?

Comment: The problem I met is that the BroadcastReceiver didn't receive any intents. There is no compilation error here. The intent-filter of the dummy activity is "android.intent.action.MAIN" as an action, and "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" as a category. There is nothing else other than them in the manifest file for the dummy activity.

Comment: Oh, I should say this. The installation has not been failed, but the BroadcastReceiver hasn't received any intents. Sorry for any confusion from my sloppy English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will this form of the APK file be installed on Android devices be installed successfully and can the BR receive intended intents?

No.

> I am not sure why, but the installation of such APK files (with a single BR) seems to fail all the time.

No, but the `BroadcastReceiver` will not receive broadcasts until something has directly invoked one of your components via an *explicit* `Intent` (i.e., an `Intent` that identifies the class). Normally, that will happen by the user launching your `LAUNCHER` activity. This has been the case since Android 3.1, about three years ago (see "Launch controls on stopped applications" in [the Android 3.1 release notes](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1.html)).

Comment: Great! Your answer is what I expected to see. The link to "Launch controls on stopped applications" looks very valuable tome. Many thanks to you and to the other helpers as well!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one `Activity` for landing page in the android app. What are you expecting will happen when the app is launched manually?